# Turtle window hanging

Tags: python, python-turtle

When I try to run my code, my python turtle window just hangs; I can't move also. I've tried removing the win_pen and it worked, but I don't know what inside the win_pen is making it hang.

It also gives me the spinning wheel since I am on Mac, and I am not sure if that is the problem for this. I'm on Big Sur 11.1 by the way.

**edit: The indents are right on my screen, just a copy and paste problem**

Code:

```
import turtle
import os
import math
import random
from random import randint

score = 0

# Set Up Screen
wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.bgcolor("black")
wn.title("test")

# Draw border
border_pen = turtle.Turtle()
border_pen.speed(0)
border_pen.color("white")
border_pen.penup()
border_pen.setposition(-300,-300)
border_pen.pendown()
border_pen.hideturtle()
border_pen.pensize(3)
for side in range(4):
border_pen.fd(600)
border_pen.lt(90)

# Draw Winning Area
win_pen = turtle.Turtle()
win_pen.hideturtle()
win_pen.shape("square")
win_pen.penup()
win_pen.setposition(0,267.7)
win_pen.shapesize(3,29.8)

# Show Score on Screen
score_pen = turtle.Turtle()
score_pen.speed(0)
score_pen.color("white")
score_pen.penup()
score_pen.setposition(-290, 303)
scorestring = "Score: %s" %score
score_pen.write(scorestring, False, align="left", font=("Ubuntu", 14, "normal"))
score_pen.hideturtle()

# Set up Player 1
player1 = turtle.Turtle()

player1.color("blue")
player1.shape("triangle")
player1.penup()
player1.speed(0)
player1.setposition(0, -250)
player1.setheading(90)

player1speed = 15

# Set Up Enemies
en = 8

enemies = []

for i in range(en):
enemies.append(turtle.Turtle())
for enemy in enemies:
enemy.color("red")
enemy.shape("square")
enemy.penup()
enemy.speed(0)
enemy.goto(randint(-280,280),randint(-280,280))
enemy.shapesize(2,2)


enemyspeed = 2

# Draw Winning Area
win_pen = turtle.Turtle()
win_pen.hideturtle()
win_pen.shape("square")
win_pen.penup()
win_pen.setposition(0,267.7)
win_pen.shapesize(3,29.8)


#Define bullet state
#ready - ready to fire
#fire - bullet is firing
bulletstate = "ready"

def left():
x = player1.xcor()
player1.setheading(180)
player1.forward(player1speed)
if x < -280:
x = - 280
player1.setx(x)
def right():
x = player1.xcor()
player1.setheading(0)
player1.forward(player1speed)
if x > 280:
x = 280
player1.setx(x)

def up():
y = player1.ycor()
player1.setheading(90)
player1.forward(player1speed)
if y > 280:
y = 280
player1.sety(y)

def down():
y = player1.ycor()
player1.setheading(270)
player1.forward(player1speed)
if y < -280:
y = 280
player1.sety(y)

def isCollision(t1, t2):
distance = math.sqrt(math.pow(t1.xcor()-t2.xcor(),2)+math.pow(t1.ycor()-t2.ycor(),2))
if distance < 15:
return True
else:
return False


turtle.listen()

turtle.onkey(left, "a")
turtle.onkey(right, "d")
turtle.onkey(up, "w")
turtle.onkey(down, "s")

# Main Game Loop
while True:
if isCollision(player1, win_pen):
player1.setposition(0, -250)
player1.setheading(90)
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation in your code.  I'm not familiar with the turtle module but I suspect the problem is the `while True:` at the bottom -- usually in a game the main loop needs to give the window a chance to redraw in between iterations.

Comment: Doing a quick google of "python turtle game" suggests that maybe you need to call `wn.update()` in your loop?  Take a look: https://www.edureka.co/blog/python-turtle-module/

Comment: ya the win.update() doesn't work, even when I put it in the right spot sadly

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your code: don't use `while True:` in an event-driven world like turtle -- let the event handler do its job; your collision logic is incorrect as it measures from the center of the turtles whereas we're really only concerned with the y position of the two turtles; you seem to be resetting the player in the wrong direction; you implement the winning area twice.

I've rewritten, and simplified, your code below incorporating the above changes and some other tweaks:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import randint

ENEMY_COUNT = 8
PLAYER_SPEED = 15

def left():
    player.setheading(180)

    player.setx(max(-280, player.xcor() - PLAYER_SPEED))

    check_collision(player, win_pen)

def right():
    player.setheading(0)

    player.setx(min(280, player.xcor() + PLAYER_SPEED))

    check_collision(player, win_pen)

def up():
    player.setheading(90)

    player.sety(min(280, player.ycor() + PLAYER_SPEED))

    check_collision(player, win_pen)

def down():
    player.setheading(270)

    player.sety(max(-280, player.ycor() - PLAYER_SPEED))

    check_collision(player, win_pen)

def check_collision(player, win_pen):
    if abs(player.ycor() - win_pen.ycor()) < 15:
        player.sety(-250)
        player.setheading(90)

score = 0

# Set Up Screen
screen = Screen()
screen.bgcolor('black')

# Draw border
border_pen = Turtle()
border_pen.hideturtle()
border_pen.pensize(3)
border_pen.color('white')
border_pen.speed('fastest')

border_pen.penup()
border_pen.setposition(-300, -300)
border_pen.pendown()

for _ in range(4):
    border_pen.forward(600)
    border_pen.left(90)

# Draw Winning Area
win_pen = Turtle()
win_pen.shape('square')
win_pen.shapesize(3, 29.8)
win_pen.color('gray')
win_pen.penup()
win_pen.sety(267.7)

# Show Score on Screen
score_pen = Turtle()
score_pen.hideturtle()
score_pen.color('white')
score_pen.penup()
score_pen.setposition(-290, 303)

scorestring = "Score: %s" %score
score_pen.write(scorestring, False, align='left', font=('Ubuntu', 14, 'normal'))

# Set up Player
player = Turtle()
player.shape('triangle')
player.color('blue')
player.speed('fastest')
player.setheading(90)
player.penup()
player.setx(-250)

# Set Up Enemies
enemies = []

for _ in range(ENEMY_COUNT):
    enemy = Turtle()

    enemy.color('red')
    enemy.shape('square')
    enemy.shapesize(2)
    enemy.speed('fastest')
    enemy.penup()
    enemy.goto(randint(-280, 280), randint(-280, 280))

    enemies.append(enemy)

screen.onkey(left, 'a')
screen.onkey(right, 'd')
screen.onkey(up, 'w')
screen.onkey(down, 's')
screen.listen()

screen.mainloop()
```